# Inserting values into Label inside of a FormView in 'Insert mode'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've done this before but for some reason this isn't working for me now.

What I have is a asp.FormView that I want to insert a value into two asp.Label(s) which I had used to replace a TextBox inserted into the FormView upon creation by the IDE.  I wanted to use the TextBox because I wanted to programmatically supply the values for these two textboxes.

This didn't error out at all but failed to populate the Label control with the anticipated value. (even though the same was possible when the FormView was in edit mode opposed to insert mode.

So I changed the label back to a TextBox from being a Label and again same results. Edit mode displays the code supplied values, while in Insert mode it would not even though tracking it in debug the value assignment was set to the binding target of the control.

I can't see what i've done wrong here as this is working in other points in the where I've wanted to feed values into the FormView while in Insert mode.

Here is the code involved:

```
/*-- This is the fragment of code in the aspx which is related to the issue: --*/
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="EditImpStndPreamble" DataSourceID="ImpStndPreambDS" OnItemCommand="EditImpStndPreamble_ItemCommand" DefaultMode="Edit" DataKeyNames="ARS_Index">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label  runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true" Width="60" Text="Index #"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("ARSEL_Index") %>' runat="server" ID="ARSEL_IndexLabel1" Width="74" />

        <asp:Label runat="server" Width="60" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true" Text="Control #"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("ARSControlNum") %>' runat="server" ID="ARSControlNumTextBox" Width="74" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>


// This is the fragmentof code in the C# code behind related to the issue

// This is where we update the control number
TextBox ctrnum = (TextBox)EditImpStndPreamble.Row.FindControl("ARSControlNumTextBox");
if (ctrnum != null)
    ctrnum.Text = Session["CurrentControl"].ToString();
```

Anyone see what I've fumbled here or have a suggestion on getting these values into the Insert mode?
Thanks!

**UPDATE: 3/21/17 8:47AM Central US time**

This morning I considered that this was a postback issue and added Autopostback="true" to each of the TextBox.

What I observed was that on the first time that I hit the code the autopostback didn't populate the TextBox. However, when I hit it a second time and came back the value was populated properly.  So, I guess the follow up would be How can I keep the control refreshing till it shows the value without forcing the user to click twice to populate the boxes?

[image]

NOTE: I've corrected the initial question to properly reflect 'TextBoxes' instead of Labels.  I will keep it as a TextBox until I have this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your entire problem, but in the snippet you provided there is no Label `ARSControlNumLabel`.

Both your labels do not have an `ID` property, so `FindControl` cannot possibly find them.

Comment: Okay I got in this morning and went to check out what you observed and this was an error in my question editing. I'd been flipping between TextBox and Label because my other pages use TextBox but I would prefer to use a Label here.  The code this morning was Label and both the aspx had a valid label as did the C# behind.  I then just to make sure it had been fully exploited switched both to TextBox. Results the same. No value displayed in Insert mode on the FormView.

Comment: Then are you sure the Sessions `CurrentControl` and `CurrentFamily` contain any data? What happens if you hard-code a value for testing?

Comment: Question has been updated (corrected Textbox issue) and provided additional information related to Autopostback on the TextBox.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer for this as the current test performed did prove successful even though it isn't working properly. I will create a separate posting for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding AutoPostBack = "true" to the embedded TextBox control allowed the value to be shown in while the FormView was in Insert Mode.